# XML - From SQL Server to LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

**Setup:**

I have some xml data stored in a database (SQL Server 2008 R2) which is retrieved via stored proc and placed into a DataTable.  The DataTable has 2 columns: a DateTime "timestamp", and an XML "info".

After pulling this data from the database, I would like to loop through each row and operate on the data using LINQ to XML in C#.

```
public static void ParseDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < dataTable.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        // dataTable.Rows[r]["timestamp"].ToString() holds DateTime
        // dataTable.Rows[r]["info"].ToString() holds XML
    }
}
```

**My Question:**

What is the simplest way to get this data into an object on which I can use LINQ?  What types of objects should be used?

**Furthermore:**

- Please don't ask why xml is stored in the database, or recommend a different storage medium.  Not looking to start a holy war.
- If the xml should be returned as a different type (e.g., `CAST([info] AS VARCHAR(MAX))`), please let me know.
- I would rather like to use LINQ to parse the object, once I have it available, so please do not recommend other methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(dataTable.Rows[r]["info"].ToString());
```

And then you can [linq away](https://stackoverflow.com/a/566180/1069200)

Comment: So easy!  Thank you.  I hadn't stumbled across XDocument.Parse(), which makes this very simple.  Plus, linking back to a Jon Skeet answer - always good. :D

Comment: It may be better to use `XElement.Parse` unless the XML in question is a full document -- see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671542/whats-the-difference-between-xelement-load-and-xdocument-load).